LaTex editor Kile does not work on Plasma 6
After upgrade to Plasma 6 Kile does not open as it does not find the Okular library anymore. The problem is that Kile has not been updated to use Plasma 6 yet and it still requires a bunch of Plasma 5 libraries.
My operating system is KDE Neon that after a recent upgrade uses Plasma 6.  I would like to continue using this system.
What can I do to run Kile on KDE Neon with Plasma 6?

if you wait, kde will publish a update for that

@killertofus Waiting for a new stable release of Kile can take years, see https://kile.sourceforge.io/news.php

report it as a bug https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided&product=kile
